# Xcode: can't find headers for device in build process

Tags: xcode, header, project, device

My builds for device keep failing, for simulator all is fine. I should note: in the past I could build for device just fine, but not anymore.

I've created a library that is the base for my project. As part of the library build process, the x86 and ARM code get merged into 1 binary, then the binary and the appropriate headers are copied to the directory `~/devel/bin`

My other project has this directory included (no copy, a link). The library is added to the target of the project and the headers are included by setting the appropriate user header search path (a subdirectory of `~/devel/bin`).

When I build for device I get the following warnings:

`/Users/user/Desktop/ProjectName/ProjectName/ViewController.m:57: error: 'service' undeclared (first use in this function)`

Service is pointer to an SDService instance (an object from the library).

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to fix this issue? I tried recreating the project, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is seriously f*cked up. Been trying to fix this issue for the last 3 or 4 hours, but finally found the solution. The issue seems to be the compiler. I switched from LLVM+GCC to LLVM 2.0. Hope everything else works fine with this compiler, but at least I can build again.